# Working with multiple projects

Tags: haskell, package, ghc

For non trivial projects is commonly split it in several packages (in particular, I work usually with Visual Studio C# solutions containing 1-10 projects).

My current Haskell workflow is perform `cabal clean && cabal configure && cabal install --force-reinstall` for each time I modify some package that is used in another one.

That's works fine but I wish work with several Haskell projects as if only one be (ideally if `A` and `B` projects was modified then using `ghci A` detect changes on `B`).

The proposed solution (if possible) should work fine too if certain package `A` (in development) is shared in several *"workspaces"*.

I looked for, but the unique related response ([Haskell Cafe, Working with multiple projects 2009](http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell-cafe/2009-November/thread.html#68956)) suggest my current workflow as solution.

Any tutorial explaining it (workspaces, shared *"in development"* packages, ...) will be welcome!

Thanks a lot!!! :)

(I'm working with `ghc`)

Comment: This is basically what I do to, but it's rather annoying. I'd love to hear of a better way to do it.

Comment: have you tried cabal-dev?

Comment: @DiegoNolan looks like great! (you may post as answer, I think is a good solution ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, basically you can use `cabal-dev` to make a local sandbox of the packages you want to use for a given project.  This is will stop different projects that may have conflicting package requirements from mucking every thing up.

Here is a good post on reddit explaining the basics.

http://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/f3ykj/psa_use_cabaldev_to_solve_dependency_problems/